# Exchange paradox: PDF over the positive reals such that f(2x) = f(x/2)?

Tags: probability, paradoxes

I was reading about the exchange paradox (two envelopes, one with $m$ dollars and another with $2m$ dollars, you get one at random, would you switch before looking?). The paradox is that if you get $X$, the expected value of switching seems to be $(1/2)*2X + (1/2)*X/2 > X$, so switching seems optimal. A resolution I read was that if you do this, you're assuming that *for all* $x \in\mathbb{R}^+$, that $x/2$ and $2x$ have the same probability, and that **no such pdf exists** because it does not integrate to 1. This statement was not supported. Is there anyway to prove or reason through this?

Answer (score 2):

It's done with integrals and $u$-substitution. If $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty f(2x)\,dx=1$, then
$$\int_0^\infty f\left(x\over 2\right)\,dx = \int_0^\infty f(2u)\cdot4\, du = 4 \cdot 1 = 4.$$ (Here, I let $u=\displaystyle{x\over4}$.)